# How to read whitespace delimited strings until EOF in R

Tags: string, r, input, eof

I am new to R and I am currently having trouble with reading a series of strings until I encounter an EOF. Not only I don't know how to detect EOF, but I also don't know how to read a single string separated by whitespace which is trivial to do in any other language I have seen so far. In C, I would simply do:

```
while (scanf("%s", s) == 1) { /* do something with s */ }
```

If possible, I would prefer a solution which does not require knowing the maximum length of strings in advance.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I am looking for solution which does not store all the input into memory, but the one equivalent or at least similar to the C code above.

Comment: `readLines` reads text until the end of file by default

Comment: I have tried scan, but it seems that it reads until EOF is encountered. I want read strings one by one, since I am reading several millions of them (I updated the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to read one item at a time... It uses the fact that `scan` has an `nmax` parameter (and `n` and `nlines` - it's actually kind of a mess!).

```
# First create a sample file to read from...
writeLines(c("Hello world", "and now", "Goodbye"), "foo.txt")

# Use a file connection to read from...
f <- file("foo.txt", "r")

i <- 0L
repeat {
   s <- scan(f, "", nmax=1, quiet=TRUE)
   if (length(s) == 0) break
   i <- i + 1L
   cat("Read item #", i, ": ", s, "\n", sep="")
}
close(f)
```

When scan encounters EOF, it returns a zero-length vector. So a more obscure but C-like way would be:

```
while (length(s <- scan(f, "", nmax=1, quiet=TRUE))) {
   i <- i + 1L
   cat("Read item #", i, ": ", s, "\n", sep="")
}
```

In any case, the output would be:

```
Read item #1: Hello
Read item #2: world
Read item #3: and
Read item #4: now
Read item #5: Goodbye
```

Finally, if you could vectorize what you do to the strings, you should probably try to read a bunch of them at a time - just change `nmax` to, say, `10000`.

Answer (score 3):

```
> txt <- "This is an example"  # could be from a file but will use textConnection()
> read.table(textConnection(txt))
    V1 V2 V3      V4
1 This is an example
```

`read.table` is implemented with `scan`, so you can just look at the code to see how the experts did it.

Comment: But this loads everything into memory, right? I need to do it in a memory-efficient way, like the C version does. I updated the original post.

Comment: Loading data into memory is the "R way". If you want a compiled language, then use a compiled language.

Comment: @DWin - I think reading one item at a time and then doing lots of calculations on it would still fit well into the R paradigm?

Comment: Y'ur right. A file connection should also work with any `scan` based solution.